# Find all strings with smallest length in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to return the smallest values from my `words` array

Finding the shortest word is easy but I am not sure how to return a new array with the shortest words.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        
        String[] words = {"What", "is", "the", "shortest", "word", "is"};
        String shortest = words[0];
        for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            if(words[i].length() <= shortest.length()){
                shortest = words[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(shortest);

    }
}
```

The expected output is something like `shorestWords [] = {"is", "is"}`

Comment: I wouldn't use an array for the result because you have to initialize an array with a capacity and that means you would have to know how many shortest words you are going to find. If you are not forced to use an arry, use a `List<String>` where you can simply `add` elements.

Comment: `String shortest` can store only *one* string. Do you know of some *thing* which can store more elements? Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the answers are not considering that result is expected in String[] instead of ArrayList, here's how I did it.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String[] words = {"What", "is", "the", "shortest", "word", "is", "on"};
    int countShortest = 0;
    int smallestLength = words[0].length();
    for (int i=1; i<words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].length() < smallestLength) {
            smallestLength = words[i].length();
            countShortest=0;
        }
        if(words[i].length() == smallestLength) {
            countShortest++;
        }
    }
    String result[] = new String[countShortest];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        if(words[i].length() == smallestLength) {
            result[k] = words[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I was looking for, I was abut 75% of the way there with my effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
// Finding the shortest length
int shortestLength = Arrays.stream(words)
        .mapToInt(String::length)
        .min()
        .getAsInt();

// Retrieve only shortest length strings
String[] shortestLengthStrs = Arrays.stream(words)
        .filter(str -> str.length() == shortestLength)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Might want to collect to an array instead of a list, as per OPs requirements.

Comment: (note that this can also be solved on a single pass)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest something like:

```
int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(String word : words) { size = Math.min(size, word.length()) };
ArrayList<String> shortest = new ArrayList<>();
for(String word : words) {
    if (word.length() == size) shortest.add(word);
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for arrays, not lists. You have to convert later.

Comment: (note that this can also be solved on a single pass)

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the length of the shortest words present and then append all the words with that length to a new List.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        
        String[] words = {"What", "is", "the", "shortest", "word", "is"};
        int shortest = words[0].length;
        for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
            if(words[i].length() < shortest)
                shortest = words[i].length;

        List<String> shortestWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        for ( int i=0; i<words.length; i++)
            if(words[i].length() == shortest)
              shortestWords.add(words[i]);
        
        // Edit-1: converting to array
        String[] arr = shortestWords.toArray(new String[0]);
        
    }
```

Comment: OP is asking for arrays, not lists. You have to convert later.

Comment: (note that this can also be solved on a single pass)

Answer (score 1):

This is over the top, but this one-line stream expression with grouping finds all of the shortest values by collecting the strings of same length into a TreeMap and then grabbing the first (and lowest length) entry:

```
String[] shortest = Arrays.stream(words)
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
           .firstEntry().getValue().toArray(String[]::new);
```

If your input can contain empty arrays, the above and some other answers here will fail, but you can handle all cases with `Optional` value around the above:

```
String[] shortest = Optional.ofNullable(
       Arrays.stream(words)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .firstEntry()
   ).orElseGet(() -> Map.entry(0, List.of())).getValue().toArray(String[]::new);
```